# Capture event when we out from text box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 3 input text box.

```
    <input type="text" id="textbox1" />
    <input type="text" id="textbox2" />
    <input type="text" id="textbox3" />
```

I want to capture that text box value when I out from that. For example I entering 'stackoverflow' in textbox2, now I click on textbox3, So now I want to capture textbox2 value. If I didn't click on textbox3 and click somewhere on screen then also I want to capture textbox2 value. In short I want to capture that box text value by which I out after entering data.

I tried with keyUp and change event but both are not full fill my requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `blur` event. You can use `focusout` too, but that does the extra work of bubbling event, which I don't think is required.

```
$('[id^=textbox]').blur(function(){
   // do something
});
```

Comment: I have different different id's, So i assign a class to every field. After i added this code: $(".updateData").blur(function(){console.log("update");}); But this code is not working.

Comment: @DesipicforuBlogspot please prepare a jsfiddle, reproducing your problem

Comment: Ohhh... Sorry my mistake. I am applying blur event before adding dynamic html to div. I fix this and code is working fine. Thanks for the help. I am looking for same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can get value of textbox using this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('[id^=textbox]').blur(function(){
    var value = $(this).val();
    console.log(value);
});
```